# C# cmd window starts to open and close after .exe file start

Tags: c#, file, copy, exe, move

When I start my exe file after copying it to another location a cmd window pops up and closes every second and the moved file does not start either.

I simply want to move my exe file to somewhere else and start it from there.

What am I doing wrong?

```
if (!File.Exists("C:\\Users\\Me\\thesoftware.exe"))
    {
        // To copy a file or folder to a new location:
        ExecuteCommand("cp thesoftware.exe C:\\Users\\Me");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        ExecuteCommand("C:\\Users\\Me\\thesoftware.exe"); // should starts exe somewhere else
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: I think that if you show the code of ExecuteCommand you will get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to execute a command to move a file. You can use `File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName)` for this operation instead of `ExecuteCommand`. And this does not popup a window. You can even check possible error conditions more easily.

Additionally `Thread.Sleep(2000);`is not needed, because after `File.Copy` returns you know that the operation has been completed.